# Mahout - Error while running trainnb

Tags: hadoop, mahout

Using Mahout seq2sparse command, I manage to successfully create the following folders in HDFS

```
df-count
dictionary.file-0
frequency.file-0
tf-vectors
tfidf-vectors
tokenized-documents
wordcount
```

After that when I run the trainnb command with the following syntax

```
mahout trainnb -i tweet-vectors -el -li labelindex -o model -ow -c
```

I get the following error. Does anyone know resolution for the same?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: hdfs://machineinfo:8020/user/hhhh/tweetvectors/df-count
        at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileDirIterator$1.apply(SequenceFileDirIterator.java:115)
        at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileDirIterator$1.apply(SequenceFileDirIterator.java:106)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
        at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:597)
        at com.google.common.collect.ForwardingIterator.hasNext(ForwardingIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.BayesUtils.writeLabelIndex(BayesUtils.java:122)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.TrainNaiveBayesJob.createLabelIndex(TrainNaiveBayesJob.java:180)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.TrainNaiveBayesJob.run(TrainNaiveBayesJob.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.TrainNaiveBayesJob.main(TrainNaiveBayesJob.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hhhh/tweet-vectors/df-count
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:2006)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSClient.java:1975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java:1967)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:735)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.openFile(SequenceFile.java:1499)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1474)
        at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileIterator.<init>(SequenceFileIterator.java:63)
        at org.apache.mahout.common.iterator.sequencefile.SequenceFileDirIterator$1.apply(SequenceFileDirIterator.java:110)
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems mahout cannot see the file `/user/hhhh/tweet-vectors/df-count` in HDFS.

First, try `hadoop dfs -ls /user/hhhh/tweet-vectors/df-count` to verify the file exists. 
If it doesn't exist, there's your problem. If it does exist, check if it is a file or a directory. mahout seems to be looking for a file, not a directory.

If is exists and it is a file, then verify that mahout is connecting to the same hadoop namenode instance where the file is stored.